# how to link css file at html page

Tags: hyperlink, location-href

i have some script..it lies in some direktori :

```
var/www/html/dataTables-1.6/media/css/demo_page.css
```

how to put in html page?

```
<link href=......??? rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Comment: Klox, for files like Javascript and CSS, you always want to include them based on their location relative to where they are being included or by the absolute URL location.  Jason McCreary has the correct answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming html is your webroot, place the following in your `head` tag.

```
<link href="/dataTables-1.6/media/css/demo_page.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
```

Is this what you were asking?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the full server path "/location/of/the/file/here.css" or you could use the relative path from where the file you are placing it in resides. "../back/one/directory.css". Or you could use the full web URL for it "http://www.yourhost/yourwebRoot/yourfile.css".